# How to get 30 seconds delay

Tags: function, vba, time

I want to generate a 30 seconds delay in vba. I can't use 'Timer' as my application will run overnight till next morning. (Timer will generate the seconds(in fraction) elapsed till midnight). Is there any other way to achieve this other than Timer and Application.WaitNow().
I tried using the following code but it throws Code execution has been interrupted error.

```
Function Wait()

Dim StartSecond
Dim EndSecond

StartSecond = Second(Now)
'Sheets("SampleOutputEx").Range("M2") = StartSecond

EndSecond = (StartSecond + 30) Mod 60                             
While Second(Now) <> EndSecond
  DoEvents
Wend

End Function
```

Comment: Why do you want to wait? You could schedule what needs to run in 30 seconds with `Application.OnTime` instead if that is applicable to your use case.

Comment: @assylias Do you mean like this? Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"), "RunProcess"

Comment: When you say that it will run overnight, do you mean it will run once overnight, or recursively all night long?

Comment: @DanielCook I'm using an external simulation tool. It'll fire results once every 30 seconds. I capture the results in excel.The application will run for continuous 77 hours.

Comment: @Code_Kid yes that's the idea.

Comment: Where do the results from the external simulation tool go? Is it a text file? CSV file? And what do you need to do with the results?

Comment: @assylias Sorry to ask this. What does Run Process mean here? The application doesn't wait for 30 seconds

Comment: @joseph4tw The simul tool will give few integer values as results. I copy it to the excel and compare with predefined set of expected values and take action based on the outcome.

Comment: @Code_Kid I see. If you could get the application to export the results to a text file, you could just connect Excel to it with a Pivot Table, have the table auto refresh every 30 seconds, and then use the Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate event and you wouldn't have to worry about "halting" execution, but rather run code when the data is updated.

Comment: @Code_Kid RunProcess is the name of a function or procedure that you want to run at the scheduled time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go. Never thought the answer could be very simple.

```
Function Wait()
Dim StartSecond As Single
Dim EndSecond
StartSecond = Now

EndSecond = DateAdd("s", 30, Now)

While Now < EndSecond
DoEvents
Wend

End Function
```

This works fine for me. Any comments regarding this are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" Alias "Sleep" _
(ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

Call this function whenever you want a sleep

```
Function Wait(Seconds as integer)

  Sleep Seconds*1000

End Function
```

You can also use

```
expression.OnTime(When, Name, Tolerance)
```

and set the time to the next execution by adding 30 seconds to current time.

[This](http://vbadud.blogspot.in/2008/03/sleep-function-in-excel-vba.html) article has a better explanation of it

Comment: Will this halt the other running applications on the system?

Comment: No it will not but will halt your vba application though

Comment: VBA does not support multithreading so the techniques you will get will either halt the application or will use time multiplexing to perform the task on scheduled basis.

Comment: +1 This is a great example both as a solution to the OP's question, and as an example for why one should definitively remove any software (Word, Excel) that is scriptable with VBA from the harddisk and block any website or email containing any snippet of VBA without further looking at it. Being able to alias and call some arbitrary function from some arbitrary system library in a scripting language is... just... scary.

Comment: Using sleep technique throws an error 'overflow'. Using Application.Wait throws Code execution has been interrupted error after 30 seconds. Timer will be just perfect. Sad i cant use it overnight.

Comment: @Code_Kid : I assume that somewhere in the code a value being passed to the function is too big for its type and hence you are getting an overflow error. Another possibility is, you are calling a recursive function (A function that calls itself) but without proper break to this process.

Comment: @Murtuza Kabul I m usng a for loop and call the wait function passing 30 seconds as argument. May i know why does my code mentioned in the question throws error?

Comment: Just try changing the line Sleep seconds*1000 with Sleep 30000 and omit the arguments at all. This should help overcome the issue

Comment: It seems like the problem is with some other part of code. Try reducing the delay to approx 1 second and debug the code step by step. Overflow error generally occurs for two reasons - Assigning a value to variable which is beyond its capicity or 2 - Calling a recursive function without having a break (which will yield stack overflow error though)